# Recover Aironet AP-ESC doesn’t seem to break c2602 boot sequence

Tags: cisco, wireless, aironet, autonomous, password-recovery

I am trying to reuse an old Cisco Aironet c2602 Autonomous AP; I need to reset the password.  CCO instructions say that I need to hit `ESC` repeatedly while I am on the console during the AP boot sequence and then rename/copy the config when I get to the ap: prompt (which should be roughly analogous to IOS `rommon>` prompt).

Ref:
https://community.cisco.com/t5/wireless-mobility-knowledge-base/password-recovery-in-autonomous-ap/ta-p/3146670

My problem is that hitting `ESC` repeatedly from initial power on until I see main aironet OS loading doesn’t break into the `ap:` prompt. I cannot find other ways to get to the `ap:` prompt… I also tried using the break command via PuTTY

This AP is running 15.3(3)JF1

How should I recover the AP at this point?

Comment: The 2600's have a physical reset button. Hold it for 30s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment on my question, [Ricky said](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/83991/recover-aironet-ap-esc-doesn-t-seem-to-break-c2602-boot-sequence?noredirect=1#comment151677_83991):

> The 2600's have a physical reset button. Hold it for 30s.

Technically that button is the `MODE` button, but yes  while the AP is off press the `MODE` button, power the AP on and keep the `MODE` button pressed for 30-seconds; ref: [Aironet 2600 Data Sheet](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/2600/quick/guide/ap2600getstart.pdf) for location of the button.

The AP LED will turn RED when the boot interruption is complete.

Once you can break the Aironet AP boot sequence, you can get to the `ap:` prompt and follow the rest of the password reset instructions on the Data Sheet, above (which amount to renaming the configuration so the AP boots to an default config, and then you can login with `Cisco` / `Cisco`):

```
ap: copy flash:config.txt flash:configBackup.txt
ap: delete flash:config.txt
```